# - Rounding a double up & removing the numbers after a decimal point -

Tags: java, math, double, tostring, rounding

Could someone tell me how I can round a double & then remove the numbers after the decimal places - & then convert this number to a String please?

e.g. start with a double value 55.6666666666667 - round it up to a double value of 56.0000000000 -

or start with 55.333333333333 - round down to a double value of 55.0000000000 -

& then remove the decimal point and trailing zeros - convert to String.

Thanks.

Comment: You've used the term "round up", so to clarify, what happens if the double is something like 55.33333; Should it still be rounded upwards to 56, or round down to 55?

Comment: Indeed, I'm very tired - thanks for noticing!

Round up & Round down would be ideal - as it's to get a percentage / grade.

Comment: Have a look at `Math.ceil()` and cast the return value to int.

Comment: I'll edit the original question.

Answer (score 5):

The best way to round a value to the nearest integer is:

```
int x = (int)Math.round(55.6666666666667);
```

`x` will be 56. You can also use `Math.ceil()` and `Math.floor()` to round up or down respectively. Finally to make `x` a string use `String.valueOf()`. Like this:

```
String xString = String.valueOf(x);
```

If you wanted to do it all on one line:

```
String xString = String.valueOf(Math.round(55.6666666666667));
```

You can read more about the `Math` class [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html) and the String class [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html).

Comment: Woops, missed this when I posted my answer. +1

Answer (score 1):

Use the `Math.round()` function. You can cast it to an `int` to eliminate the decimal places, or you can use `Math.floor()` or `Math.ceil()` to round it down or up before casting.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you don't actually want to save the rounded value, but just want to see it as a string, this should do everything you want, where `x` is the `double`:

```
String s = String.format("%.0f", x);
```